# xscreensaver doesn't read configuration after reboot

Tags: screensaver

Recently I decided I do not want to use `xscreensaver` default screen saver and right now I am using videos instead. This is my `~/.xscreensaver` configuration part:

```
programs:                                                                     \
    mpv --shuffle --really-quiet --no-audio -fs --loop=inf \
    --no-stop-screensaver --wid=$XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW /home/user/ScreenSavers/*.mkv
```

I lock the screen and videos are being played.

However, when I rebooted the machine, old screen savers were being used, not my videos. I thought that I didn't save the `~/.xscreensaver` file, so I used `vim` to edit/browse through the file again and the `programs: mpv --shuffle...` was intact. As usual, I pressed `:wq`, locked the screen again and videos were being played.

So I rebooted the machine and again, locked the screen and still I had screen savers instead of videos.

In order for the videos to be played, I need to `touch` the `~/.xscreensaver` file. On a side note, after `touch` only the date on file is changed.

My question is, can anyone explain this behaviour?